# React-native Build failed in USB debugging with galaxy J5

Tags: react-native

I've already done a debugging with moto G and moto G4, but with galaxy J5 show these issues:

> BUILD FAILED in 7s

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you enable developer mode in J5?

Comment: yes, i have enable developer mode and USB debugging, I tried in J5 Prime and it works normally. Maybe it's a error in device